# Securing API of Application that uses Sign in with twitter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, api, twitter

I'm developing an application which uses "Sign in with Twitter" functionality as the login mechanism. As part of this application I'd like to develop an API for users to interact with aswell.

My question then is how would I go about securing my API when I don't have any authentication details of my own?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add an API token system where a user could request a token, and that token would be associated with their account, and used in their API requests. You can see how other APIs, like the amazon web services use a token in their authorization scheme, you will have to build something similar: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader